# Django: Redirect to another page after download triggered

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to redirect to another page after a download is triggered.

My code is:

```py
animated_gif = BytesIO()
frames[0].save(animated_gif,
                format='gif',
                save_all=True,
                append_images=frames[1:],
                )
animated_gif.seek(0)
response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/gif")
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s.gif" % "new"
response.write(animated_gif.getvalue())
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a redirect `return redirect("main:homepage")`
replace what is in quotes with the url you want to redirect to.